# Clear Application's Data Programmatically

Tags: android

I want to clear my application's data programmatically.

Application's data may contain anything like databases, shared preferences, Internal-External files or any other files created within the application.

I know we can clear data in the mobile device through:

> Settings->Applications-> ManageApplications-> My_application->Clear
>   Data

But I need to do the above thing through an Android Program?

Answer (score 147):

There's a new API introduced in API 19 (KitKat):
[ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#clearApplicationUserData()).

I highly recommend using it in new applications:

```
import android.os.Build.*;
if (VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    ((ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .clearApplicationUserData(); // note: it has a return value!
} else {
    // use old hacky way, which can be removed
    // once minSdkVersion goes above 19 in a few years.
}
```

If you don't want the hacky way you can also hide the button on the UI, so that functionality is just not available on old phones.

Knowledge of this method is mandatory for anyone using [`android:manageSpaceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#manageSpaceActivityName).

---

Whenever I use this, I do so from a `manageSpaceActivity` which has `android:process=":manager"`. There, I manually kill any **other** processes of my app. This allows me to let a UI stay running and let the user decide where to go next.

```
private static void killProcessesAround(Activity activity) throws NameNotFoundException {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String myProcessPrefix = activity.getApplicationInfo().processName;
    String myProcessName = activity.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(activity.getComponentName(), 0).processName;
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo proc : am.getRunningAppProcesses()) {
        if (proc.processName.startsWith(myProcessPrefix) && !proc.processName.equals(myProcessName)) {
            android.os.Process.killProcess(proc.pid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: for me .clearApplicationUserData(); is force closing the app as well.

Comment: Check your logcat: "it crashes" doesn't mean anything without an Exception/stacktrace. Also you may need some permissions (e.g. write external storage?).

Comment: Then it's probably something after, check the logs!

Comment: It has to kill the app, or else it could have data it is holding on to that will get written back.  The only safe way to do this is to (1) kill the app, (2) clear all of its data, (3) next time the app starts up it will start fresh with no data.

Comment: Hi @TWiStErRob I want to implement this method when clicked on LOGOUT button in my application. But it force closes the app. Instead I want to start the main activity where the signup/sign in form is present.. How will this be possible?

Comment: @pblead26 see update, if you need more than this, please open a new question, as your followup is unrelated to this current question OP asked.

Comment: @Dharmendra sorry, just a utility method to deal with `NameNotFoundException`, I inlined it. This exception shouldn't be thrown in this case because we're querying the current *running* activity.

Comment: Can you maybe explain how to call the killProcessesAround method? I dont get where/how it should be used?

Comment: @Lichtamberg see hackbod's comment. I call it right before calling `clearApplicationUserData`.

Comment: So you mean like this? try {
                    killProcessesAround(CurrentManageSpaceActivity.this);
                    ((ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Comment: For pre KitKat version see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23470355/3256989

Comment: is it possible to start any other activity after apply this code

Comment: @AmandeepRohila When I use the `android:process` attribute as described I still have a running activity that's part of the app, so after the `clearApplicationUserData()` returns you should be able to fire up another activity with `startActivity` as usual. Make sure you call clear in background and start the activity on the UI thread! It's also advised that your other process doesn't use any files/db/prefs, just a plain activity.

Comment: @TWiStErRob I want to launch an activity with a dialog after invoking `clearApplicationUserData()`. I am trying to use the steps outlined with a separate activity using the `android:process` but calling `clearApplicationUserData()` seems to kill everything. Is this not possible?

Comment: As far as I know it's impossible to run anything after calling this function, because it acts exactly as clear-data. I've made a request to improve it, here:https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/174903931 . Please consider starring.

Comment: @androiddeveloper and it is marked as "Won't Fix"

Answer (score 111):

I'm just putting the tutorial from [the link ihrupin posted](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically) here in this post.

```
package com.hrupin.cleaner;

import java.io.File;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void clearApplicationData() {
        File cacheDirectory = getCacheDir();
        File applicationDirectory = new File(cacheDirectory.getParent());
        if (applicationDirectory.exists()) {
            String[] fileNames = applicationDirectory.list();
            for (String fileName : fileNames) {
                if (!fileName.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteFile(new File(applicationDirectory, fileName));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteFile(File file) {
        boolean deletedAll = true;
        if (file != null) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                String[] children = file.list();
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    deletedAll = deleteFile(new File(file, children[i])) && deletedAll;
                }
            } else {
                deletedAll = file.delete();
            }
        }

        return deletedAll;
    }
}
```

So if you want a button to do this you need to call MyApplication.getInstance(). clearApplicationData() from within an onClickListener

**Update:**
Your `SharedPreferences` instance might hold onto your data and recreate the preferences file after you delete it. So your going to want to get your `SharedPreferences` object and

```
prefs.edit().clear().commit();
```

**Update:**

You need to add `android:name="your.package.MyApplication"` to the `application tag` inside AndroidManifest.xml if you had not done so. Else, `MyApplication.getInstance()` returns `null`, resulting a **NullPointerException**.

Comment: Take care ! You remove everyting in the app folder, including share preferences.. not only the cache dir itself and its content.

Comment: I have implemented this solution . But my application data is not cleared only cache is cleared.. 5 MB is still remaining.. any other solution?? Please help me out :(

Comment: @MinceMan Please mention that this must be writted in class that extends Application for better effect

Comment: Very smart to keep the lib dir.

Comment: To people posting updates, it'd be good to either make the updated text flow with the rest of the text, or specify from when the updates apply.

Comment: yes it removed all files but app not realized it so i still could be files on app dir. App realized clearing after remove app from recent app thren start it. I tried to recreate activity but it not work

Comment: how can i use this and still keep the shared preferences file without uploading it to a server or anything like that?

Comment: Either don't call `prefs.edit().clear().commit();` or add `prefs.edit().commit();` to have your prefs recreate it after you deleted it.

Comment: Why isn't the 'lib' directory removed?

Comment: One benefit of this approach is that it does not reset user granted permissions like activityManager.clearApplicationUserData() does.

Answer (score 24):

combine code from 2 answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42228794/1815624
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29197259/1815624

Here is the resulting combined source based answer

```
private void clearAppData() {
    try {
        // clearing app data
        if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData(); // note: it has a return value!
        } else {
            String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec("pm clear "+packageName);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Will this work on all Android devices irrespective of the Android version? For me, it works on all 3 Android devices I own (with Lollipop, Marshmallow and Pie)

Comment: yea the if else is for equal or less than kit kat ...use clearApplicationUserData and above it uses runtime.exce... basically a shell command ...pretty reliable other than permissions...it should just work...

Answer (score 2):

What I use everywhere :

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm clear me.myapp");
```

> Executing above piece of code closes application and removes all databases and shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

If you want a less verbose hack:

```
void deleteDirectory(String path) {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("rm -rf %s", path));
}
```

Comment: You may want to quote that path in case it has spaces and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
private void clearAppData() {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
            ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData();
        } else {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm clear " + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to this or a link to where you got it from please?