# reset Android application to initial state

Tags: android

Is there any way I can reset all application data? I mean, database, cache, application folder, etc. I want to do it when applications `onDestroy()` is called. I am looking for a global solution - I don't know created tables in database, I know only package name.

Comment: [Clear Application's Data Programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programatically)

Comment: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0483.html

Comment: Well, I know all of these, they are pretty much the same. But it doesn't workk perfectly. I was looking for something like universal android built-in method that does it

Comment: I think global solution is, you know what you are creating in your app just delete those things, e.g. if you are creating sharedprefs, delete it using SharedPreferences.Editor.clear().commit(), you can delete database using context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME), etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
public void clearApplicationData() {
            File cache = getCacheDir();
            File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
            if(appDir.exists()){
                    String[] children = appDir.list();
                    for(String s : children){
                            if(!s.equals("lib")){
                                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                                    Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s +" DELETED *******************");
                            }
                    }
            }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return dir.delete();
    }
```

Courtesy hrupin. For more click [here](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically)