# Delete all sharedPreferences in Android

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, instrumentation

Is it possible to programmatically delete all sharedPreferences of an Android application, without knowing the file names? I mean all files, not all keys of a given file.

I'm running unit tests with instrumentation for several applications, and i need to clear every file the an app may create under `/data/data/app.package.name/shared_prefs` folder.

For example an app may create these files under shared_prefs:

```
appname.xml
app.package.name_preferences.xml
app.package.name_tips.xml
```

while for another app i could have:

```
app.package.name_prefs.xml
app.package.name_foo.xml
```

Note: Using `pm clear YOUR_APP_PACKAGE` the app crashes.

Thanks

Comment: @codeMagic why duplicate? Actually i asked a different question from the one you linked

Comment: The accepted answer tells you how to clear the preferences which is what you are asking to do

Comment: post edited. Here i found what i was looking for: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/9073473/4512309](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9073473/4512309)

Answer (score 3):

To remove all prefs of the application you can use:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor.clear()
```

After that you have to `commit()` the removal.

So it would look like that in full code:

```
getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0).edit().clear().commit() // change PREF to yours
```

Comment: By doing this i need to specify PREFS, but i don't know the filename in advance, i need to clear all preference files

Comment: Then you can try to use `getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`: `getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().clear().commit();`

Comment: Only `app.package.name_preferences.xml` gets cleared, other xml files are still untouched.

Comment: .xml? I thought you just wanted to remove all saved shared preferences? Now I see, you edited your questions...

Comment: Aren't those "shared preferences" too? I thought that anything inside /shared_pref would be considered shared preferences. Android is a bit confusing sometimes..

Comment: @mcns7 What other xml files do you want to delete?

Comment: every file that an application may create inside `/data/data/shared_prefs`, i don't know filenames though, my code will test several applications