# App Data contains large files

Tags: java, android, file, java-native-interface, apk

The `/data/app/package` folder of my app contains large amount of files.

This is the breakdown of the files

`/data/app/package/lib/arm/` folder contains one file `libsupportjni.so` which is of no use to me and also is not needed by me. This file occupies around 1.1 MB space.

`/data/app/package/` folder contains one `base.apk` file of my app which occupies around 22 MB of space.

My question is whether is it possible to remove all the file while the IDE(Android Studio) is building the signed apk file.

All these file together increases the size of my app by 50%.

Comment: _"folder contains one base.apk file of my app which occupies around 22 MB of space."_ See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/LO2tU4ACbU4 for more info.

Comment: You do not control either one of those things. If you want your APK to be smaller, use the APK Analyzer in Android Studio to identify what is contributing to that APK, and try to reduce it (e.g., eliminate large dependencies).

Comment: @CommonsWare This size is after the app is installed in the phone. But I don't understand why there is `.apk` of my app itself inside that folder. Also I am not using any JNI code so why is there any library for that. The size of my apps apk file is only 4MB. But the apk file inside the data directory of my app only is 22MB. Any idea

Comment: As I wrote, you do not control either one of those things. That behavior is up to the OS developer and the device manufacturer.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. But this was fine before I made upgraded to Android Studio 3.0. I don't unfortunately know what were the changes while migrating from 2.0 to 3.0 which caused this error.

Comment: There is no error. If you are using Instant Run, try disabling it, and perhaps some of these items will no longer be in your app's portion of internal storage.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. Had a look but this is talking about the `apk` file. But my question is that why there is a 22MB file occupying space in my apps Data after I has been installed.

Comment: @RajeshK: That's what the discussion I linked to is about; i.e. what the purpose is of keeping the APK on the device after installation. And the reasons I gathered were 1) resource files are not extracted and will be read from the APK, and 2) to enable incremental upgrades of apps.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the better and clear clarification. But can you please explain why the `libsupportjni.so` is there and how it can be removed as I no longer need it. Please Help.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not using Instant Run. But I don't need the `libsupportjni.so` file as I have NO JNI code in my app. But I was planning to have some sometime before but dropped the plan. May be because of that it is there. Is it possible to remove that?

Comment: @RajeshK: Google suggests it has something to do with enabling Advanced Profiling in Android Studio. Though I don't really see why you're worried about what files you have on your test device. Is the .so file included in the APK that you publish on Google Play?

Comment: As I keep saying, you do not have control over that. If the IDE is putting it there, your users are not using an IDE. If the OS is putting it there, that is the OS's decision, not yours. Focus on controlling what is inside your APK file.

Comment: @Michael Yes it is included. Which increases the size of the app after installing from 24 MB(Including all data) to around 44MB.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your help. I have to use an old backup of the same app which was saved by few days ago. Whose size is 50 % of the current size.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your help. I have to use an old backup of the same app which was saved by few days ago. Whose size is 50 % of the current size. But can you post an answer for the `.apk` file so that I can accept it and someone else can be benefited from that.