# libsupportjni.so files added in the project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

As my application is approaching completion, I was analyzing my apk using Android Studio. I saw a sudden increase in apk size:

[image: APK Analyzer. lib folder 43.4%, res folder 32.2%, classes.dex 20.4%]

The `lib` folder which is occupying 10mb space has only these files:

[image: libsupportjni.so for various CPU architectures]

I am sure that I don't have any native dependencies, but I am not sure how these files came here. Can anyone help me, I want to remove these files from my application.

**Edit 1**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.2'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.3.0'
    //implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
    implementation 'it.sephiroth.android.library.targettooltip:target-tooltip-library:+'
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:2.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //Needed for custom web view implementation
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'

}
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49773996/app-data-contains-large-files

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncheck **Enable advanced profiling** option from

**Run** -> **Edit Configurations** -> **Profiling** -> **Enable advanced profiling**.

[image]

If you simply want to exclude the **`.so`** files, can try below inside your `android {}` of `app/build.gradle`

```
android { 
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/x86/libsupportjni.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libsupportjni.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libsupportjni.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libsupportjni.so'
    }
    ...
}
```

Adding the the previous answer, you can try 'Build > Clean Project' and then 'Build > Rebuild' after disabling 'Advanced Profiler'. It also reduced apk size.

Comment: I tried this, before even posting this question here, but to no avail.

Comment: excluding something like this, will it not break anything in my app??

Comment: If you are sure, those jniLibs are not from your sources or dependencies, then it should no impact with your app logic

Comment: Okay, I know that my app doesn't have any native dependency, is there a way to know if any of my dependencies have transitive dependency on a native library?

Comment: By trying out my answer, how does you app go now?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Shizhen's answer, after disabling Advanced Profiling, I tried doing **Build > Clean Project** and then **Build > Rebuild Project** and it drastically reduced the apk size.

Comment: It's better to edit his answer or quot important part in your's