# How to use a .so library during compile time only?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a third party `.so` library which I need to use at compile time only in my application. The provider of the library says:-

> NOTE: DO NOT include thelibrary.so as part of agent APK. Use for compilation purpose only.

I have this in my `build.gradle`:-

```
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
       def ndkDir = project.android.ndkDirectory.absolutePath
       project.logger.debug('my debug message')
       if (ndkDir == null) {
             ndkDir = "/usr/local/bin"
        }
       commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath, // Change src/main/jni the relative path to your jni source
            '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
            'all',
            'NDK_DEBUG=1'
      }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
```

and the `Android.mk` file looks like this:-

```
    LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)
    LOCAL_MODULE:= mymodulename
    LOCAL_STL := c++_static
    LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -llog
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -fuse-ld=bfd
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ljnigraphics
    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -landroid
    LOCAL_LDLIBS +:= -Lmylibrary.so <-------THIS IS THE THIRD PARTY LIB
    LOCAL_LDFLAGS:= -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= mylocalfile_using_thecode_from_so_file.cpp
    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I know I can add the `myLibrary.so` as a separate module and package it as a `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY`, but the provider of the library has said that it should not be packaged along with the apk, and should be used at compilation only.

How do I add this library for compilation only?

I am not using cmake. This is a legacy project and there is no goal to upgrade it for some reason.

---

**UPDATE #1**

We were using another version of this library in the project. Let us call it **Version 1** and were including **Version 1** as a `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY`. However when I use the newer **Version 2** of the same library as a `PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY`, it complains

> cannot locate symbol "_ZNK7android8String164sizeEv" referenced by thefinalbuiltlibrary.so .

Regarding the ignore all symbols `LDFLAG` :- It is one of the many things I am just trying to make this work.

Comment: Umm...  I think you need to say a bit more about what's going on.  Why do you need the library?  What happens if you don't supply it?  You are ignoring undefined symbols... What has changed to make this all necessary?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike added an update to the question above.

Comment: That still doesn't make much sense. `_ZNK7android8String164sizeEv` is android::String16`, which is not an NDK API. If that's not being provided by your application, you're incorrectly loading it from the system, and that is only going to work on pre-N devices. If it _is_ provided by your app, then it shouldn't matter which library you build against so you should just build against the one you ship.

Comment: `LOCAL_LDFLAGS:= -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all` this flag just turns build errors into runtime errors. I'd recommend removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I add this library for compilation only?

Probably you are trying to exclude that shared library when do apk packaging. Putting below snippet into your `app/build.gradle` can achieve this:

```
android { 
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/x86/thefinalbuiltlibrary.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/thefinalbuiltlibrary.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/thefinalbuiltlibrary.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/thefinalbuiltlibrary.so'
    }
    ...
}
```

See: [libsupportjni.so files added in the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851099/libsupportjni-so-files-added-in-the-project/53861215#53861215)