# **EDIT** How to set a cache clearing button in my android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, directory, android-webview

**I want to place a button on that app that will clear the cache of my android app. Anyone know if that's possible?**

Edit:
This is my **MainActivity** code, that I use in my application.

```
package nl.giuliandenicola.giuliansportfolio;

import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(5 * 1024 * 1024); // 5MB
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); // load online by default

        if ( !isNetworkAvailable() ) { // loading offline
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
        }

        webView.loadUrl("http://google.com" );
    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService( CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE );
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete cache of your own application then simply delete your cache directory

```
public static void deleteCache(Context context) {
    try {
        File dir = context.getCacheDir();
        deleteDir(dir);
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
    else if(dir!= null && dir.isFile())
        return dir.delete();
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

in your manifest file in order to delete cache of other application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE"/>
```

check answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/9073473/2826147

Comment: And how will I make it so it will work with the "OnClick" function?

Comment: call this method on your **OnClick** function pasing parameter.

Comment: Wait this code, I need to place it inside the MainActivity right? ( I'm just beginning with android studio.

Comment: Yes, inside mainactivity.