# Delete Firebase Persistence data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase data persistence in my app. When I logout of the app, I want to clear the Firebase cached data as well. The persisted data is hampering the behavior of my app.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281761/clear-firebase-persistence-after-logout), I understand that it needs to be worked around. If Firebase stored data in SQLite, how can I delete this SQLite file programmatically?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281761/clear-firebase-persistence-after-logout ?

Comment: Yes, I will alter the question.

Comment: u can clear or deleted the files folder from the local directory