# Android:Firebase: How to clean active sessions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In Digits if I need to clear all active session I use method:

```
Digits.getSessionManager().clearActiveSession();
```

Is it possible to do same in Firebase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clear firebase persistence after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281761/clear-firebase-persistence-after-logout)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike from Fabric & Firebase here.

I believe you're looking for:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

which would sign the user out of the active session. For reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#next_steps