# Getting same results with realtime database even when data has changed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I do a query on a path then add new data on the same path then read again with the same query and the new data is not in the result. I can see the new data in my FB console and if I restart my app, it will show. It's like I'm reading from cached data. What is wrong?

```
public static void GetScores(string readDbPath)
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference(readDbPath).OrderByChild("score")
        .LimitToLast(Constants.FIREBASE_QUERY_ITEM_LIMIT)
      .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
      {
          if (task.IsFaulted)
          {
              // Handle the error...
              Debug.LogError("FirebaseDatabase task.IsFaulted" + task.Exception.ToString());
          }
          else if (task.IsCompleted)
          {
              DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
              // Do something with snapshot...
              List<Score> currentScoreList = new List<Score>();
              foreach (var rank in snapshot.Children)
              {
                  var highscoreobject = rank.Value as Dictionary<string, System.Object>;

                  string userID = highscoreobject["userID"].ToString();
                  int score = int.Parse(highscoreobject["score"].ToString());
                  currentScoreList.Add(new Score(score, userID));

              }
              OnStatsDataQueryReceived.Invoke(currentScoreList); // catched by leaderboard
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: Maybe it **is** cached? Maybe this helps: [Clear firebase persistence after logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281761/clear-firebase-persistence-after-logout) ?

Comment: How are you viewing results?  The viewer many not get repainted.  For example a DGV to view new results you have to set output to null and then back to the source : datagridview1.DataSource = null; datagridview1.DataSource = dt;

Comment: @derHugo it is cached indeed but I need to clear the cache before the user wants to view the leaderboards not after logout

Comment: @jdweng results are viewed in a Unity made UI. It is a mobile app. It is not mentioned explicitly but I put a Unity tag when asking the question

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that you're using Firebase's disk persistence, which doesn't work well with `Get` calls. For a longer explanation of why that is, see my answer here: [Firebase Offline Capabilities and addListenerForSingleValueEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486417/firebase-offline-capabilities-and-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent/34487195#34487195)

So you'll have to choose: *either* use disk persistence, *or* use `Get` calls. The alternative to calling `Get` would be to monitor the `ValueChanged` event. In this case your callback will be invoked immediately when you change the value in the database. For more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [listening for events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#listen_for_events).

Answer (score 0):

This post was deleted  stating it was just additional infos on my question. If fact it is the solution which is to use GoOffline() / GoOnline().

Thanks Frank for the detailed answer.

I tried with

FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.SetPersistenceEnabled(false)

but the problem stayed the same. Using listeners is not what I want since every time a player would send a score, every player on the same path would receive refreshed data so I'm worried about b/w costs and performance.

The best solution I just found is to call before using a get

FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GoOnline();
then right after I get a response I set

FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GoOffline();
So far no performance hit I can notice and I get what I want, fresh data on each get. Plus persistence if working off line then going back.