# how to delete app data backup programmatically

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I am building an app and the feature to automatically backup the data is set as below:

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

I need to delete this data. I can't ask the user of the app to delete the backup itself or disable the data sync.

Is there a way to programmatically ask for?

Thanks

Comment: Its already answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-pro grammatically

Comment: @user3268059 the linked thread doesn't answer this question. It answers how app data can be deleted programatically, not how a backup on Google's servers can be deleted.