# Clear App Data in android and iOS in react-native project?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

HI I know similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programmatically) is asked before. The mentioned solutions aren't helpful.

1. Tried this `

   ```
     File cache = getReactApplicationContext().getCacheDir();
       File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
       if (appDir.exists()) {
           String[] test =  cache.list();
           Log.d("before", Arrays.toString(test));
           for (String s : test) {
               //if (s.contains(".pdf") || s.contains(".mp4")) {
                   deleteDir(new File(cache, s));
                   Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
              // }
           }
           Log.d("After delete", Arrays.toString(cache.list()));
       }

   public static boolean deleteDir(File dir)
   {
       if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
           String[] children = dir.list();
           for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
               boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
               if (!success) {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       }
       return dir.delete();
   }
   ```

` but nothing happened

2. Tried this `

   ```
    try{
    if (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
               ((ActivityManager) getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)).clearApplicationUserData(); // note: it has a return value!
           } else {
               String packageName = getCurrentActivity().getPackageName();
               Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
               runtime.exec("pm clear " + packageName);


      } 
     } catch(error){console.log("error"+error)}`
   ```

got warning in console  Require cycles are allowed, but can result in uninitialized values. Consider refactoring to remove the need for a cycle. app is exited which is not encouraged.
I need to show the login page after cleaning data.

Any Insights ???

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
```

/* you can add conditions here when to clear data*/

```
this.clearApplicationData();

initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
```

}

```
 public void clearApplicationData() {
File cache = getCacheDir();
File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
if (appDir.exists()) {
  String[] children = appDir.list();
  for (String s : children) {
    if (!s.equals("lib")) {
      deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
      Log.i("TAG", "File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED");
    }
  }
}
```

}

```
  public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
  String[] children = dir.list();
  for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
    if (!success) {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

return dir.delete();
```

}