# Is it possible to restart Android App after calling ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData()

Tags: android, android-intent

My current Android Application needs to call

```
 ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData()
```

to simulate the user clearing App storage

Which works fine.

A side effect of calling `clearApplicationUserData()` is that the App is (understandably) closed.

Which gives a poor user experience.

I am having difficulty in restarting my Application once I have called `clearApplicationUserData()`.

I have tried using `startActivity`, `Alarm Manager` with `Pending Intent`, `Foreground`/`Background` service.

Nothing works.

Is it impossible to restart an Android App having called `clearApplicationUserData()`?

Comment: My guess is that your app winds up in the stopped state, as if the user had clicked "Force Stop". All outstanding alarms, jobs, etc. will be canceled. "Is it impossible to restart an Android App having called `clearApplicationUserData()`?" -- I doubt that is possible from within your own app. Show a message to the user explaining that this will happen before calling that method, and the user can restart the app from the launcher.

Comment: I think this what its build for .. Alarm Manager with Pending Intent, Foreground/Background will get clear anyway ..If you are going to use `clearApplicationUserData` then this will be the desired flow .. You can checkout the source code for it ..

Comment: @CommonsWare is there anyway I can enable verbose logging (or similar) to see what actually happens on calling this method?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "what actually happens", but you can view Logcat to see what is getting logged. If you are viewing it from within Android Studio, toggle the severity filter to "verbose" and ensure the end drop-down is set to "No filters", to see all messages.

Comment: @Hector is the target device rooted?

Comment: @HeltonMalambane no

Comment: I've been down a similar path in the past. Ultimately, it was easier to manually wipe the database & shared preferences and relaunch the `MainActivity`. If this is at all possible, it's strongly recommended! If not, perhaps something like scheduling a task with `WorkManager` (that isn't(?) affected by clear app data) to launch your activity?

Comment: @JakeSteam workManager employs an sqlite database to control jobs, this database is totally removed when you call clearApplicationUserData(). so this approach is a non starter

Comment: @Hector I see, it was a guess. Any chance of manually wiping your own data and relaunching activity?

Answer (score 5):

(*1st answer*: this answer only works on limited situations. it's not a complete answer)

public boolean clearApplicationUserData ()

[Description](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#clearApplicationUserData())

**Return**: `true` if the application successfully requested that the application's data be erased; `false` otherwise.

As the reference website stated, we have a returnee before the application is being closed. so, we are going to use this returnee in order to restart the app.

```
if(ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData)
{
     doRestart = true;
}
```

when Activity `onDestroy()` and `onStop()` are called restart app.

```
   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       if(doRestart){
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
           this.startActivity(intent);
       }
   }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(doRestart){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

We put restart action in both `onDestroy()` and `onStop()` in order to make sure the app will be restarted again.

And also, I think it's a good idea to force stop activity before OS stops it.

```
if(ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData)
{
     doRestart = true;
     finish(); <= i mean this 
}
```

it's because it makes sure that `onDestroy()` and `onStop()` will be invoked.

Comment: After calling `ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData()` the app process gets force-killed. No other line of code is executed.

Comment: @Onik did you tried that ? when Activity get closed , always onDestroy() is called .and also official source says it returns a boolean otherwise it should do return void .

Comment: Of course I tried, why would I write the comment with such a detailed information? If you have another method invocation behaviour, I guess there is difference in the API implementations, which makes your solution OS version specific.

Comment: @Mr.AF thanks for taking the time to answer. I will try your solution for sure

Comment: @Onik see my next answer :)

Comment: @Onik might be useful to you .

Comment: @Onik i just like to know you idea noting else .

Comment: Ok. My idea is that it might work. The OP is probably going to test it.

Comment: @Mr.AF I've tried your approach and sadly it doesn't work.

Comment: @hector which of them 1th, or 2th

Comment: @Mr.AF 1st (1th :)) the approach overriding onStop() & onDestroy() to restart App. when I try this, neither of these methods gets called

Comment: This is not a valid solution, neither onStop() nor onDestroy() is called after `ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData()`

Comment: @Micer, Yeah right but you should consider the date it was post and the Android version on that time. something that's acceptable in the past may not be acceptable in future. everything may change

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion might sound trivial but, have you consider not calling `ActivityManager.clearApplicationUserData()`?

Here what the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#clearApplicationUserData()) says about this method:

> Permits an application to erase its own data from disk. This is
>   equivalent to the user choosing to clear the app's data from within
>   the device settings UI. It erases all dynamic data associated with the
>   app -- its private data and data in its private area on external
>   storage -- but does not remove the installed application itself, nor
>   any OBB files.

So in order to mimic this behavior you just need to clear you internal and external storage directories. No permissions are needed to access any of those.

Answer (score 2):

(*2nd answer*: I need much more contribution on it)

After 8 hours of researching in Android OS and [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/) Website in order to find a solution to restart activity when `clearApplicationUserData` is invoked. Finally, I would be able to find a *nice/hacking* solution.

This solution looks like **Zidane dribble** :)

Let's introduce the solution. at first, `clearApplicationUserData` clears all the clues of the application when is invoked like *tasks, notifications, alarms* and etc. therefore, **explicit** Activity calling **is impossible**.

**implicit** way is the **only possible** way of calling activity.

After a couple of tests I found that application `manifest` registered `intent-filters` **wouldn't be removed** and they are able to listen for incoming **system broadcasts**.

Approximately, **98%** of system broadcasts wouldn't be received by **cleared application** and that **2%** remained might not be broadcasted very soon.

so what to do? hmmm? come on man I must find a solution ...

bingo,  ** I must trigger something in order to system broadcast it** <= looks hacking :)

so I decide to choose **WIFI_STATE_CHANGED** because

- Easy Access permission
- System Broadcasts it on delay <= *this makes sure that the app is closed
  before broadcast*

manifest.xml

```
<receiver
   android:name=".PackageDataClearedReceiver"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:exported="true">
     <intent-filter android:priority="100">
       <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
       <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActivityManager am;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AppCompatButton btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        if (am != null) {
                            ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
                            final Collection<Future> futures = new HashSet<Future>();
                            futures.add(pool.submit(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                                    am.clearApplicationUserData();
                                }
                            }));
                            for (Future future : futures) {
                                future.isDone();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

demo

[image]

keep in mind,  it's just A minimum viable product that needs to be developed more in order to make it work perfectly.

Comment: this approach will not work for my application as I already detect changes in WIFI state to display messages to my users, If I take your approach in 2th solution everytime WIFI state changes I will start my main activity

Comment: @Hector yup , it need much more development and customizing to your need as I said it's minimum viable product.you need to customize it

Comment: @Hector you need to put conditions in Receiver in order to restart activity when it is need

Comment: @AFarmanbar  : what is `PackageDataClearedReceiver` ?

Comment: @MehulKabaria it's just a simple broadcast receiver that starts the activity.

Answer (score -2):

Clearing the app data on the device through the API `clearApplicationUserData()` resets the app as if it were just installed. As you have found, any alarms and broadcasts registered with your app are also cleared. The most efficient way to keep your app in the foreground would be to clear the data yourself, as others have pointed out, rather than using the API. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9073473/949224

---

*However*, if you are determined to use the API (which does guarantee all data is cleared) and the app is force-stopped, I have a suggestion:

Create a small companion app that can be launched just prior to you clearing your app data. The companion app simply re-launches your app, possibly after a short time-out.

```
    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("example.com.testrelaunchapp");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        startActivity(launchIntent);//null pointer check in case package name was not found
    } else {
        Log.w( TAG, "Unable to resolve launch activity of relauncher companion app");
    }

    ((ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                    .clearApplicationUserData();
```

The companion app itself needs to close afterwards, and ideally should be hidden from the Activity Stack etc..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("example.com.yourmainapp");
    if (launchIntent != null) {
        Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i( TAG, "About to act on launchIntent");
                launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                launchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(launchIntent);
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }    
 }
```

I have seen this work with Android 6.0, but no guarantees it would be versatile and work across the board. There would be more to do to make the companion app UI-less if desired and to be hidden from the phone's launcher. You would also probably want to bundle the APK as a file within your own app and install it upon first run, which would need the user to enable installation from "Unknown sources" (non-Play store). It can be done through intents to the right System settings, if needed, but users would need a good explanation why this is needed.

So, as I was saying, the simpler approach is to clear the data and app permissions yourself.

Comment: i think it's not workable solution . because you solution needs extra installed packages that makes it impossible . and if we were be able to have extra packages or companion apps then there would be  a lot of ways starting activity .

Comment: It's certainly possible to prompt the user to install another app from your own. The question is whether you want this behaviour as part of how you operate. As I mentioned, I would not recommend it, but it's still worthy of mentioning the idea in principle in case its useful to others.