# How to clear app data in android app using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to delete my app data programmatically using `Kotlin` as my programing language but did not find any solution.

I have a `WebView` and it is reloading my `URL` after a specified time period. After the specified time is over I want to delete my app data and reload my `WebView` to delete any stored `cache` or other files stored from the previous website visit.

**What I tried so far**

```
package com.technosoftkpk.y_view
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlin.concurrent.thread
import kotlin.random.Random


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val myWebView: WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview)
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.technosoft.eu")
        val webSettings = myWebView.settings
        webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true

        //Random Timer To reload the page
        thread {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(5000)
                // How to add function below to delete app data programmatically after the above time period.
                // function bla bla bla here


                Thread.sleep(5000)
                runOnUiThread { myWebView.reload() }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I hope you will understand what I am trying to do. Thanks in advance

Comment: Detailed Answered by @TWiStErRob
[Answere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29197259/3546909)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear Application's Data Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programmatically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to answer my question here because I found the perfect solution to my problem.

My `function` for clearing app data.

```
private fun deleteAppData() {
        try {
            // clearing app data
            val packageName = applicationContext.packageName
            val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
            runtime.exec("pm clear $packageName")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

My call to this `function` after some time period via `thread`

```
thread {
       while (true) {
       Thread.sleep(5000)
       runOnUiThread { deleteAppData() }
       }
     }
```