# Remove everything from previous app install

Tags: android

We have rebuilt our app from the ground up with all new functionality and want to remove all of the previous data when the user upgrades to the new version.

Complication:  in the previous app, file names and database names were dynamically generated off user account values, so we need to remove them without knowing their exact names.

Complication #2:  The previous app was done by an outside agency. I don't know everything they saved and where. So I'm looking to go nuclear here.

Would this do it?  Am I missing anything?  Is there a better way?  Thanks in advance!

```
private const val LEGACY_PREFS = "old_shared_prefs"

fun deleteLegacyAppData(context: Context) {
    context.cleanUpLegacySharedPrefs()
    
    // this call assumes that the new code base
    // with the same package name would retrieve
    // the same filesDir
    context.cleanUpLegacyData(context.filesDir)
}

private fun Context.cleanUpLegacySharedPrefs() {
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences(LEGACY_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    prefs.edit().clear().apply()
}

private fun Context.cleanUpLegacyData(file: File) {
    if (file.isDirectory) {
        for (f in file.listFiles() ?: emptyArray()) {
            cleanUpLegacyData(f)
        }
    }
    file.delete()
}
```

Comment: "Would this do it?" -- we have no way of knowing, as we do not know what you stored originally. "Am I missing anything?" -- databases, `SharedPreferences` other than the one that you are handling, and `getCacheDir()` come to mind with respect to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), but we do not know if you used any of that. "Is there a better way?" -- there is [a `deleteRecursively()` extension function on `File`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/delete-recursively.html) that you could use.

Comment: @ArtemViter "Page Not Found"

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, there's my problem.  The previous app was done by an outside agency.  I don't know everything they did.  So I'm looking to go nuclear here.  Clear everything possible

Comment: @Psest328 sorry , try look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programmatically

Comment: @ArtemViter I saw this but apparently it kills the app, which we can't have happen, so I'm looking for a way to do it manually

Comment: @Psest328 Did you see all answers? for example by `MinceMan`