# Can android macro benchmark run without clear app's data?

Tags: android, performance

Can android macro benchmark run without clear app's data?

because in my app it require user to accept the license, and the macrobenchmark clear app's data every time when it startup the application.

Comment: is this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programmatically#answer-29197259

Comment: @RobinHood don't think that's relevant here considering OP is asking about the Macro benchmark specifically

Answer (score 0):

To bring your app to a specific state before starting to measure with macrobenchmark, use the `setupBlock` in the `measureRepeated` function:

```
benchmarkRule.measureRepeated(
        packageName = PACKAGE_NAME,
        metrics = listOf(StartupTimingMetric()),
        iterations = 5,
        startupMode = StartupMode.COLD,
        setupBlock = {
          acceptLicense() // <-- Use UIAutomator to perform user actions
        }
    ) {
        // Perform benchmark actions
    }
```

Comment: That's not helpful.  My app loads something that's set up on the first run on non first runs.  You just can not get the performance of typical run when  the data is cleared.  No amount UIAutomator can simulate a non-frist run.

Comment: Exactly, we do integrity checks only for first launch and not on every subsequent cold start launches.  But with the above setup it will repeat on every iteration and wont provide real world data.