# Android Studio - fresh install the app each time I run

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there a way to do a fresh install each time I run the app from Android Studio? I'm trying to iron out the bugs for 1st time users.

Similar to this [How can I clear my app's localStorage on my Android emulator each time I install it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142069/how-can-i-clear-my-apps-localstorage-on-my-android-emulator-each-time-i-install)

but for Android Studio

Comment: Uninstalling the apk from Android Studio sounds like a solution. [Try looking here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927124/how-to-uninstall-apk-or-execute-adb-command-automatically-before-run-or-debug).

Comment: @GPL That's looks like it'll do the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea why SO moved my answer to the comments section of the question, but I'm going to shamelessly repeat the answer for some points :-).

Uninstalling the apk from Android Studio sounds like a solution. [Try looking here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927124/how-to-uninstall-apk-or-execute-adb-command-automatically-before-run-or-debug).