# Clearing data in Android and open the MainActivity.java file

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I am working on a application which takes a user's mobile number and stores the number in a file locally and stores it in a cloud database as well . I have written application logic in such a way that if the user exits from the app it maintains the state. When user opens the App again, the home page is opened with the same mobile number. I want to clear the all the data on Logout button click, and then again want to open the `MobileHarvestMainActivity.java` file (ask to enter the number again from user).

I tried the link [How to programmatically clear application data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856955/how-to-programatically-clear-application-data) — it worked but when using the intent to send the MainActivity page App crashes.

```
logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.KEYBOARD_TAP);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            Intent intent = new Intent(ListeningAndSharingHomeActivity.this,MyActivity.class);
          //  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // To clean up all activities
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();



        }
    });

}



public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


    clearApplicationData();


    }

    public void clearApplicationData() {

    File cache = getCacheDir();

    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());

    if (appDir.exists()) {

    String[] children = appDir.list();

    for (String s : children) {

    if (!s.equals("lib")) {

    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
    Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");

    }

    }

    }
    calling();
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {

    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {

    String[] children = dir.list();

    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {

    boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));


    if (!success) {

    return false;

    }

    }

    }

    return dir.delete();


    }
```

void calling()
{

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MobileHarvestMainActivity.class);
//intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

Comment: You're accessing the first index of an array or list that has no elements in it (which probably means its a list).  Either ensure it always has something in it, or check the size before trying to call get on it.

Comment: The code for logout was invisible - enclose text in `<angle brackets>` inside back-quotes ``like `<these>` backquotes`` — or, more relevantly, put it into an edit of the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Sir, i have edited the code plz help me now..thanks for your co-operation

Comment: I got the solution .. the clearing cache is working properly. problem was with my main Activity...thanks

Comment: The Link is very usefull for the same kind of thinghttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/6134103/clear-applications-data-programatically