# Initiating "Clear data" for an app from settings in app code (Android)

Tags: android

I know this may seem as a silly question, but is it possible?

In cause you are wondering why am is asking this... I made an update to an app of mine that, if installed over the previous versions, it make it crash in a certain vital point, and it will only work if you go to settings and "Clear Data". I was wondering if i could use some code snippet to make this automatically for this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better fix to your problem would be to figure out why it is crashing at this point and to address that. You can likely make use of the SqliteHelper#OnUpgrade method to accomplish this.

that being said. I assume that this would fix your problem:

```
 File dir = context.getFilesDir();
 FileUtils.cleanDirectory(dir);
```

That gets the private file directory for your application and clears it, which is essentially what the clear data function will do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to delete the `SQLite` file and `SharedPreferences`.

You can do some answers in this question :

[How to programmatically clear application data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856955/how-to-programatically-clear-application-data)