# Android - How to programatically clear app (calendar) data

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm trying to delete the data inside an application from a custom application but am not sure how to to get this done. To be more specific i'm trying to:

Application manager --> calendar storage --> clear data

I was looking at [How to programmatically clear application data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856955/how-to-programmatically-clear-application-data) but i'm not sure how to get the database for the calendar storage as well.

Hope to get some feedback.

Comment: Um, you cannot clear the data of another app, except on a rooted device.

Comment: @CommonsWare oh that's unfortunate. i wasn't aware of this. Thanks for the reply